# (R) How can I force substitution of a vector element in a formula?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a formula that is expressed in terms of an element of a vector.  However the element is not substituted when the formula is built; instead it is left in as a component---I'd prefer if the actual value was substituted in immediately.  (This breaks something else later in the code.)

```
c <- c(5:8)  #made a vector on purpose, even though only use c[1]   
form <- as.formula(y ~ exp(-(x-c[1])^2/2))
```

at this point `form` contains `y ~ exp(-(x - c[1])^2/(2))` but I'd like it to contain `y ~ exp(-(x - 5)^2/(2))`.

Comment: Here's one option: `form <- as.formula(substitute(y ~ exp(-(x-d_)^2/2), list(d_ = d[1])))`; where I renamed your vector `c` to `d`.

Comment: or `as.formula(sprintf('y ~ exp(-(x - %s)^2 / 2)', c[1]))`

Comment: rawr -- thank you!!  While I accepted the `bquote` below as it was the best way to solve the problem I gave, it wound up not working in my code since I had made my question too simple.  `sprintf` was exactly what I needed -- and I'm an old C programmer, I should have guessed it was around somewhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `bquote` makes it pretty easy to plug vlaues into formulas. For example

```
form <- bquote(y ~ exp(-(x- .( c[1]) )^2/2))
form
# y ~ exp(-(x - 5L)^2/2)
```

Note it add the "L" to indicate an integer literal value (as opposed to a general numeric value). This is because `5:8` creates an integer vector.